# WebView não abre popup - Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8-1, webview

Estou tentando obter uma autenticação por uma URL, ate ai tudo traquilo. Mas no site, que estou tentando a autenticação, é possível logar com o facebook mas, ao utilizar essa alternativa, ao invés da pagina de login/autorização do facebook aparecer no próprio componente (WebView) ele chama o browser padrão do SO, o que faz com que a autenticação não funcione. Minha duvida é, como fazer ele abrir essa popup do facebook no próprio componente? Obrigado.

C#

```
private void wvwTeste_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string _clientId = "123456";
    wvwTeste.Navigate(new Uri("https://api.teste.com/oauth/?" +
                                                    "response_type=code&" +
                                                    "redirect_uri=https://localhost/&" +
                                                    "client_id=" + _clientId + "&" +
                                                    "scope=read_public,write_public&" +
                                                    "state=768uyFys", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <WebView x:Name="wvwTeste"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             Visibility="Visible" 
             NavigationCompleted="wvwTeste_NavigationCompleted" 
             Loaded="wvwTeste_Loaded" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Opa, dá uma olhada nesse [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2013/10/19/how-to-popup-a-xaml-webview-ui-async-and-wait-for-results/) aqui.

Comment: Não é isso. Eu não quero abrir o WebView em uma pop-up. O que eu quero é que as pop-ups não sejam direcionadas ao navegador do SO. Nessa autenticação, quando acessada no navegador, ao tentar logar pelo Facebook abre uma pop-up. O que preciso é que quando tentar esse método, logar pelo Facebook, a pop-up seja aberta no próprio webView, e não no navegador padrão do SO.